# how to find from which residual of model a specified value belongs in R

Tags: r, lm

I have created a model and I need to know from which residual the value belongs.

```
#the value is 

3.098765

#I am using following code

which(Mod3$residuals == 3.098765) #and it throws following error
named integer(0)
```

Comment: try something like: `which.min(abs(Mod3$resdiuals - 3.098765))`. The number you quote has almost certainly been rounded or truncated to 6 decimal places. This will get you to the value of `Mod3$residuals` which is closest to 3.098765.

Comment: That message is not an error. It simply means that a row with that *exact* residual cannot be found. @jlhoward has explained why.

Answer (score -1):

`residuals` are numeric. `"3.098765"` means character. Try:

```
which(Mod3$residuals == 3.098765)
```

Comment: this is also not working same error

Comment: If that had been the problem the error message would have been different. Note that in R: `1 == "1"` returns
[1] TRUE. This is clearly a floating point representation issue rather than a type mismatch issue.

Comment: Try: `any(Mod3$residuals %in% 3.098765)`? Perhaps there is no such a value in your residual? Or would that be a rounding issue? i.e. `any(round(Mod3$residuals, 3) %in% round(3.098765, 3))`